# Django sqlite column not found error

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I'm having a little trouble querying my sqlite DB. Has anyone seen this before? It may very well be that I am doing something silly

Here we have the schema:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "homepage_user" (
    "username" varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homepage_oncall" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES "homepage_user" ("username"),
    "start_date" datetime,
    "end_date" datetime
)
;

COMMIT;
```

And then when I query that data from django's interactive shell:

```
...
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT user_id from homepage_oncall').fetchall()
[(u'amencke',), (u'jdoe',), (u'jbloggs',)]
```

However - any attempt to query 'homepage_oncall.user_id' will be met with a stern rebuke:

```
>>> query = cursor.execute('SELECT first_name, last_name FROM homepage_user WHERE homepage_user.username = homepage_oncall.user_id AND NOW() BETWEEN homepage_oncall.start_date AND homepage_oncall.end_date')
...
DatabaseError: no such column: homepage_oncall.user_id
```

I had a look around on here and it seems this issue surfaces after editing a schema after it was created - but (after failing to solve the problem with 'manage.py migrate' I actually deleted and recreated the entire database to rule that out - there was nothing in it anyway

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Why are you writing raw SQL in Django anyway?

Comment: It seemed like a good idea at the time. Thanks for your input - I'll take a look at the alternatives to raw sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your SQL. You `SELECT` from *one table* and try to apply a `WHERE` condition on another table without performing an implicit or explicit `JOIN`.

Also Django provides a pretty nice ORM, so I would recommend sticking to it instead of running raw queries against the database especially if you are not well versed with writing SQL queries

Comment: Thanks @Emma. I'm no expert in SQL but after a quick search for sql JOIN I solved my problem.